How to open *.docx file with editor of the OS?
On laravel 10 / filament 3 site I create and save *.docx file with "Word2007" format using phpoffice/phpword library under site
storage(I keep path of the generated file). After saving of the file I need to open the file with editor which is used for this type of file
in the OS of the user. I search OS independeble desicion . How can I do it ?
UPDATED :
I have installed this  https://github.com/pxlrbt/filament-excel plugin
which generate/upload a file in browser's download functionality.
I my app I generate my document in action of file EditEmployee.php:
protected function getHeaderActions(): array
{
    return [
        Actions\DeleteAction::make(),
        Action::make('GenerateWordCard')
            ->label('Generate card in word-file')
            ->action(function (array $data, array $arguments): void {
                $employeeCard = new GenerateEmployeeCard;
                $employeeCard->setEmployee(employee: $this->record, showHireInfo: true);
                $employeeCard->generate();
                $ret = $employeeCard->download();
                $destFilename = $employeeCard->getDestFilename();
                Notification::make()
                    ->title('Employee card was successfully generated and downloaded as "' . $destFilename . '" file!')
                    ->success()
                    ->send();
            }), // Action::make('GenerateWordCard')

    ];
}

I know how to download generated file in pure laravel :
public function download(): \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse
{
    $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($this->phpWord, $this->outputFileFormat);
    $filename = 'subscriptions-of-the-app.docx';
    $objWriter->save(storage_path($filename));

    return response()->download(storage_path($filename));
}

and file is generated  and dowloaded. user can open it.
But in this app action is in getHeaderActions and it returns array.
and I do not see how can I response to download the file ?
    "php": "^8.2",
    "filament/filament": "^3.2-stable",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.48.14",
    "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.2"

Thanks in advance!

Pls , look at UPDATED

Unfortunately you can NOT do it, Word documents are not part of W3 standard.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
